# Approach for Multi-class Classification of texts

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, transformer, bert, text-classification

I'm trying to do a project where I have paragraphs and I need to classify them into multiple labels. The dataset is around 40k rows with labels.
I understand there is no one right approach but should I consider typical ML classifiers like embeddings + Logistic regression, xgboost etc.
Or should I directly consider fine tuning transformers like BERT,DistilBERT etc.

My priority is on getting accurate predictions and I have a few weeks to complete this.